# I can't make a search-and-replace script for Python

Tags: python, replace

I've been trying to do this, but I'm pretty new at Python, and can't figure out how to make it work.

I have this:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input(['tooltips.txt'], inplace=True, backup="bak.txt"):
    line.replace("oldString1", "newString1")
    line.replace("oldString2", "newString2")
```

But it just deletes everything from the txt.

What am I doing wrong?

I have tried with print(line.replace("oldString1", "newString1")
but it doesn't remove the existing words.

As I said, I'm pretty new at this.
Thanks!

Comment: `inplace` pipes `stdout` to the input file. You have to `print` the resulting line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`line.replace()` doesn't modify `line` it *returns* the modified string

```
import fileinput, sys

for line in fileinput.input(['tooltips.txt'], inplace=True, backup="bak.txt"):
    sys.stdout.write(line.replace("oldString1", "newString1"))
```

Comment: this deletes the text from the file still, and simply prints out the answer. to me, it seems clear he wants to replace the text in the actual file

Comment: @DanielWaltrip, `fileinput` substitutes `sys.stdout` while it is running and sets it back when it's finished. You have to refer to it as `sys.stdout` as a previous reference to `stdout` would not be referring to the correct file

Comment: @kashbel what I expect is you've deleted your file by your unsuccesful attempts on the first run since you have `inplace=True` which would have left your input file empty... Have you checked that ?

Comment: Ignore my last comment, it works perfectly. Thanks. Now, could you tell me how to save the replaced file to a new file? Instead deleting and backing the old one.

Comment: Oh interesting, with updated imports and reference to `sys.stdout`, it works for me. Thanks for clarifying. I was a bit hasty with the downvote, I apologize. Just read about [downvote etiquette](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down), and won't make the mistake again!

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do this is with the `open` function and the `os` module:

```
import os
with open(tmp_file) as tmp:
    with open(my_file) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            tmp.write(line.replace("oldString1", "newString1").replace("oldString2", "newString2") + "\n")
os.remove(my_file)
os.rename(tmp_file, my_file)
```